# Horizontal Menu should scroll left & right if number of items increases

Tags: jquery, html, css, jcarousel

The Horizontal menu in my website goes out of the page (leading to horizontal scroller which looks very bad).

I have a dynamic menu, if number of items(options in menu) increases, it crosses the boundary & goes out. I want to use jQuery where if number of item increases, will display icons (left & right arrows). On click of these icons - the menu should scroll left & right.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapperClass">
<div id="mainContainerClass">
<!-- Horizontal Menu Starts Here -->
    <div id="menuContainer">
    <ol id="menuList">
      <li><div id="popupmenu"><a  href="page1.html" ><span>Menu Item 1</span></a></div>  </li>
      <li><div id="popupmenu"><a  href="page2.html" ><span>Menu Item 2</span></a></div>  </li>
      <li><div id="popupmenu"><a  href="page3.html" ><span>Menu Item 3</span></a></div>  </li>
      <li><div id="popupmenu"><a  href="page4.html" ><span>Menu Item 4</span></a></div>  </li>
      <li><div id="popupmenu"><a  href="page5.html" ><span>Menu Item 5</span></a></div>  </li>
      <li><div id="popupmenu"><a  href="page6.html" ><span>Menu Item 6</span></a></div>  </li>
      <li><div id="popupmenu"><a  href="page7.html" ><span>Menu Item 7</span></a></div>  </li>
      <li><div id="popupmenu"><a  href="page8.html" ><span>Menu Item 8</span></a></div>  </li>
      <li><div id="popupmenu"><a  href="page9.html" ><span>Menu Item 9</span></a></div>  </li>
      </ol>  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapperClass { width:1000px;   margin: 0px auto;   padding:0px;}
div#mainContainerClass { margin:0px auto; width:990px;}
div#menuContainer {background:url(/menu_bg.png) repeat-x; height:38px; margin:0px auto; clear:both;}
ol#menuList {list-style: none;    margin: 0;    padding: 0; font-weight:bold;   font-size:12px; color:#EFF4F5;  padding:11px 0 0 0px;   margin:0 0 0 13px;  }
ol#menuList a {    background:  url(/tabs.png); display: block;height:26px; padding: 0 0 0 10px;    text-decoration: none;  text-align:center;  color:#EFF4F5;}
ol#menuList a:hover {    background-position: 0 -52px;}
ol#menuList a:hover span {    background-position: 100% -52px;}
ol#menuList li {    float: left;    margin: 0 1px 0 0;}
ol#menuList li.current a {    background-position: 0 -26px;    color: #fff;    font-weight: bold;   height:26px;    color:#000;}
ol#menuList li.current span {    background-position: 100% -26px;}
ol#menuList span {    background: url(/tabs.png) 100% 0;    display: block;    line-height: 2.2em;    padding-right: 10px;}
#popupmenu div{     position: absolute; visibility: hidden; min-width:100px;    margin: 0;  padding: 0; background: #0e3d95;    border: 1px solid #0e3d95;}
#popupmenu div a    {           position: relative;     display: block;     margin: 0px auto;       padding: 5px 10px;      width: auto;        height:16px;        white-space: nowrap;        text-align:left;        font-weight:bold;       text-decoration: none;      background: #EAEBD8;        color: #154aa4;     font-size:11px;
    background:url(/bg_popupmenu.png) repeat-x top left;        }
#popupmenu div a:hover  {   background: #11439d;        color: #FFF;}
```

Second Example:

```
    <div id="secondMenue" >
<a href="page1a.html" class="othermenu">Sec Item 1</a>  | 
<a href="page1b.html" class="active">Sec Item 2</a>  |
<a href="page1c.html" class="othermenu">Sec Item 3</a> |
<a href="page1d.html" class="othermenu"> Sec Item 4</a>  |
<a href="page1e.html" class="othermenu">Sec Item 5</a> 
</div>
#secondMenue{background:url(/othermenu.png)  repeat-x top center; width:975px;height:36px; margin:0px auto;font-size:11px;color:#004990; padding:10px 10px 0 5px;  text-decoration:none}
a.othermenu:link{font-size:12px;color:#004990;
padding:0 10px 0 10px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal;}
a.othermenu:visited{font-size:12px;color:#004990;padding:0 10px 0 10px;text-decoration:none;}
a.othermenu:hover{font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;color:#000;padding:0 10px 0 10px;text-decoration:none;}
a.othermenu:active {font-size:12px;color:#004990;padding:0 10px 0 10px;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;}
```

***I have this below layout for which I need to apply carousel. Request you to have a look.*** I Cannot change this as the menu layout is rendered like this

```
'<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 1</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 2</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 3</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 4</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 5</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 6</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 7</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 8</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 9</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 10</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 11</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 12</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 13</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 14</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table><tr><td><a href="#"><span>Menu Option 15</span></a></td></tr></table></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>'
```

Comment: Please shrae your current code if you want an example ... show your effort at least your HTML and CSS.

Comment: you need to post some codes before we can help you. And preferably in a jsfiddle

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Comment: Thank you all.  I have added code in my question. please check & help me.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to submit a code by the way .. any way, you may need to use the

```
overflow:hidden
```

so you don't have scrolling bar

Here is a full [JS fiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WsMg2/show/) for what you thinking about according to what I understand and here is [the code page](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WsMg2/)

What I did is two CSS cases for the menu to switch between with jQuery windows.resize()

## CSS

```
body {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;}

.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.menu {width:100%; overflow:auto;list-style: none; height:32px; white-space:nowrap}
.menu li {height:32px; background:#eee; margin-left:5px; padding:5px; float:left }
.menu.text li {width:200px;}
.menu.icons li {width:32px; background:#ffcc00}
.menu.icons li a{text-indent: -9999px; display:inline-block}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: auto;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

## jQuery

```
$(function () {
    var win = $(window);

    win.bind(
    'resize',
    function () {
        setMenu();
    }
).trigger('resize');

});

    function setMenu() {
        var _menu = $('#menu').width();
        var _width = (Math.floor(_menu));
        if (_width < 1025) {
            $('#menu').removeClass("text").addClass("icons");
        } else {
            $('#menu').removeClass("icons").addClass("text");
        }
    }
```

## And the HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="menu" class="menu text">
        <li class="nav">
            <a class="navtab" href="#">Item one</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav">
            <a class="navtab" href="#">Item two</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav">
            <a class="navtab" href="#">Item three</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav">
            <a class="navtab" href="#">Item four</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav">
            <a class="navtab" href="#">Item five</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav">
            <a class="navtab" href="#">Item six</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav">
            <a class="navtab" href="#">Item seven</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav">
            <a class="navtab" href="#">Item eight</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav">
            <a class="navtab" href="#">Item nine</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav">
            <a class="navtab" href="#">Item ten</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

## Another solution

Add a jQuery carousel .. I have added [one here for your code example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ek472/3/)

## Update:

According to your last update and f you don't have any other concerns, you may use the RenderMode to change the ASP.NET menu from table to list

```
<asp:Menu ID="YourMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="menu" RenderingMode="List" >
```

Comment: Thank you hsobhy. I tried this, but in my case menu increases horizontally. I dont need scroller, there should be some icons to scroll my menu left / right. I have added code in my question. please check.

Comment: why not then you use some type of jQuery carousels .. I have added one here for your code example http://fiddle.jshell.net/ek472/3/show/ and here is the code page  http://fiddle.jshell.net/ek472/3/

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped. But, in my case, Iam using <asp:menu> which renders menu in table mode. We cannot use list. I have edited my question. Please check last part of my question where I have the table layout to which we have to apply carousel. I tried using yours code but its giving problem as my layout is table. Request you to check this once. Thank you for your support.